# Delete using PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I perform delete operation using PL SQL by giving input file? I do not want to risk deleting directly from the table. Is it possible to delete by giving values as input? If so how?

Comment: what is your actual problem!.elaborate your situation

Comment: what do you mean by NOT DELETE FROM THE TABLE DIRECTLY.where else you want to delete?

Comment: The situation is to delete 10K entries from a table. I have those ids with me in a file and i only want to delete those from the table. So how do I delete by giving a input file?

Comment: "NOT DELETE FROM THE TABLE DIRECTLY" by this i meant that i do not want to give a condition in the snippet like "delete from xxx where condition1 and condition2"

Comment: You mean,you want to delete the entries in the table whose id is in the file.Is it?

Comment: There is no way you can delete from a table without using `delete`. So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: My question is to delete by giving a input file in the PL SQL snippet and without giving conditions. Can you get me? 

For ex : 


Delete from table where employee_id in one.txt;

Comment: You mean,you want to delete the entries in the table whose id is in the file.Is it? 

Yes. I want to delete entries from a table whose ids are in a file.

Comment: option1:try using a IN clause if have the patience to copy and format all the ids in the file option2: copy file in a temporary table and select the ids in from the temp table in a query that deletes the records

Comment: Your example, `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID IN ONE.TXT`, is not valid SQL in Oracle, nor in any database I've ever worked with. File operations are not integrated with SQL. Your options are to write procedural code to read the file and perform the deletes, or to define an external table which allows the external file to be treated as a table. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
For extracting data using plsql only.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:68212348056

**OTHER METHOD**

1) Transfer data from FILE into a Temporary table, using shell scripting(like BASH).

2) Then use Temporary table to delete the data from main table.

3) You'll then have extra advantage for doing same operation again and after just setting the Cron jobs

**SAMPLE SCRIPT FILE**

```
#!/bin/ksh
ORAENV_ASK=NO
export ORAENV_ASK

ORACLE_SID=newsp1
inputFileBkUpDir=/usr/users/backup
inputFileDir=/usr/users/file
LogDir=/usr/users/log
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/9.2.0.6

export ORACLE_SID
export ORACLE_HOME
export inputFileBkUpDir
export inputFileDir
export LogDir

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH

. oraenv

# Log File
LOGFILE=$LogDir/EDI_file_`date +%y%m%d`.log;


# Create backup directory if its not created
if ! [ -d $inputFileBkUpDir ]
then
    mkdir $inputFileBkUpDir
fi


if ! [ -d $LogDir ] 
then
  echo 'LogDir not exists'
    echo "Trying to create directory" 
    mkdir $LogDir 
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Log Directory " $LogDir " creation problem\nCannot continue process" >> ${LOGFILE}
        exit
    fi
    echo 'after LogDir created'
else
    chmod 777 $LogDir
    echo log permission changed of $LogDir
fi



#*********************************** FILE EXECUTION START ***********************************************

echo "\n>>> ******Processing File - STARTED at `date '+%d-%m-%Y %T %Z'`******">> ${LOGFILE}

sqlplus TEST_USER/PASS_USER << EOF
set serveroutput on;
spool /usr/users/spool.lst
delete from new_t.data;
commit;
spool off
exit
EOF

echo "\n>>> Check if EDI file has arrived - STARTED at `date '+%d-%m-%Y %T %Z'`">> ${LOGFILE}

for entry in "$inputFileDir"/YOUR_FILE*.dat;
do
  if [ -f "$entry" ];then
    echo "\n>>> Files present in input directory $inputFileDir">> ${LOGFILE}
    echo "\n>>> $entry" >> ${LOGFILE}
    echo "\n>>> Loading $entry file data for EDI DUMP\n" >>${LOGFILE}

    sqlldr TEST_USER/PASS_USER control=/usr/users/control.ctl data=$entry log=$LogDir/fileLoader.log
    echo 'Total number of Records Successfully Loaded         \t\t\t\c'>>$LOGFILE; grep 'Rows successfully loaded' $LogDir/fileLoader.log | awk '{print $1}'>>$LOGFILE
    echo 'Rows not loaded due to data error                   \t\t\t\c'>>$LOGFILE; grep 'Rows not loaded due to data errors' $LogDir/fileLoader.log | awk '{print $1}'>>$LOGFILE
    echo 'Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed\t\t\t\c'>>$LOGFILE; grep 'Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed' $LogDir/fileLoader.log | awk '{print $1}'>>$LOGFILE
    echo 'Rows not loaded because all fields were null        \t\t\t\c'>>$LOGFILE; grep 'Rows not loaded because all fields were null' $LogDir/fileLoader.log | awk '{print $1}'>>$LOGFILE
    echo "\n>>> Data loaded from $entry file" >>${LOGFILE}

    mv $entry $inputFileBkUpDir
    echo "\n>>> Moving $entry file to archive path $inputFileBkUpDir" >>${LOGFILE}

  else
    echo 'Files not present' >> ${LOGFILE}
  fi
done

echo "\n>>> ******Data Load Completed******" >>${LOGFILE}

echo "\n>>> ******Processing Started FILE TO DELETE DATA******" >>${LOGFILE}

sqlplus TEST_USER/PASS_USER << EOF
set serveroutput on;
spool /usr/users/spool.lst
@/usr/users/Data_Processing.sql;
spool off
exit
EOF
echo "\n>>> ******Processing complete- Data DELETED******" >>${LOGFILE}
echo "End of the script">> ${LOGFILE}
```

**SAMPLE CONTROL FILE TO SET HOW TO READ IDS FROM YOUR FILE TO TEMP TABLE**

```
LOAD DATA
        APPEND INTO TABLE COLSIMS.EDI_DATA_LOAD
        (
          S_NUMBER        POSITION(1:25),
          P_CODE          POSITION(26:50),
          P_NUMBER        POSITION(51:80),
          T_TIMESTAMP     POSITION(406:417) date "YYMMDDHH24MISS",
          L_TIMESTAMP     sysdate
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can load the file as an external table

then write a query to delete entries using entries from the external table

eg.

```
delete from yourtable where id in (select id from extTable)
```

some documentation for external tables:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm

another approach is to generate delete statements using a script outside of oracle/sql (eg excel) and then execute your delete statements

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these ID values are stored as one ID per line in a file and that the ID values are numbers the following should get you started:

```
DECLARE
  fHandle        UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  strBuffer      VARCHAR2(32767);
  nRows_deleted  NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('some_directory', 'filename.dat', 'r');

  LOOP
    BEGIN
      UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(fHandle, strBuffer);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  -- end of file
        EXIT;                  -- exit the loop
    END;

    DELETE FROM SOME_TABLE
      WHERE ID = TO_NUMBER(strBuffer);

    nRows_deleted := nRows_deleted + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Changes committed');

  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Completed successfully, ' || nRows_deleted || ' rows deleted');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLCODE  || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
    ROLLBACK;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('All changes ROLLED BACK');
    RAISE;
END;
```

## EDIT

As an alternate option, you could define an external table to allow your file to be treated as a read-only table:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_FROM_FILE
  (ID     CHAR(10))
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
    (TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY some_directory
     ACCESS PARAMETERS
       (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        FIELDS (ID  CHAR(10))
       )
     LOCATION ('filename.dat'));
```

which would then allow you to do something like

```
DELETE FROM SOME_TABLE
  WHERE ID IN DATA_FROM_FILE;
```

Share and enjoy.